# Ubuntu 23.10 freezes

Tags: freeze, crash, 23.10

I am using Ubuntu 23.10 for 2 months(new users) and it freezes frequently and can not can not restore it. The entire screen freezes. Does not recover by itself. Mouse does nothing. Keyboard shortcuts do nothing. I have to hold the power button down for 10 sec to crash it, then turn it on again, which often causes me to lose quite a bit of whatever I was working on.I also update and upgrade every time.

The problem mostly occurs when

1. When saving a document in LibreOffice.
2. When using browsers like edge or brave,especially if I have an HDMI monitor connected.
3. When I using VScodium or VScode

**Memory Usage:**

Total: 7248
Used: 2644
Buff/cache:2354

Swap Memory:
Total: 4094
Used: 0

**Logs**

Output of `journalctl -b -1 -e`:

```
    Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010027
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring kiq_0.2.1.0 test failed (-110)
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ enable failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume of IP block <gfx_v9_0> failed -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(10) failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset end with ret = -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GPU Recovery Failed: -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos systemd[1307]: snap.discord.discord-b152f024-cb2c-47d1-8488-3d6775fd1c07.scope: Consumed 35.988s CPU time.
Jan 06 11:04:34 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:36 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:38 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
lines 955-1000/1000 (END)
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay >
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010027
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ enable fa>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resu>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(10) failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset end with ret = -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GPU Recovery Fa>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos systemd[1307]: snap.discord.discord-b152f024-cb2c-47d1-8488-3d6775>
Jan 06 11:04:34 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
lines 955-998/1000 100%


Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta u>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010027
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *E>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ enable failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume o>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(10) failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset end with ret = -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GPU Recovery Failed>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos systemd[1307]: snap.discord.discord-b152f024-cb2c-47d1-8488-3d6775fd1c>
Jan 06 11:04:34 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:36 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:38 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
lines 955-1000/1000 (END)
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010027
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring kiq_0.2.1.0 test failed (-110)
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ enable failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume of IP block <gfx_v9_0> failed -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(10) failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset end with ret = -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GPU Recovery Failed: -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos systemd[1307]: snap.discord.discord-b152f024-cb2c-47d1-8488-3d6775fd1c07.scope: Consumed 35.988s CPU time.
Jan 06 11:04:34 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:36 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:38 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
~
~
lines 955-1000/1000 (END)
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010027
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring kiq_0.2.1.0 test failed (-110)
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ enable failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume of IP block <gfx_v9_0> failed -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(10) failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset end with ret = -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GPU Recovery Failed: -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos systemd[1307]: snap.discord.discord-b152f024-cb2c-47d1-8488-3d6775fd1c07.scope: Consumed 35.988s CPU time.
Jan 06 11:04:34 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:36 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:38 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
lines 955-1000/1000 (END)
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay >
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010027
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ enable fa>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resu>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(10) failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset end with ret = -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GPU Recovery Fa>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos systemd[1307]: snap.discord.discord-b152f024-cb2c-47d1-8488-3d6775>
Jan 06 11:04:34 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
lines 955-998/1000 100%


Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta u>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010027
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *E>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ enable failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume o>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(10) failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset end with ret = -110
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* GPU Recovery Failed>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos systemd[1307]: snap.discord.discord-b152f024-cb2c-47d1-8488-3d6775fd1c>
Jan 06 11:04:34 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:36 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
Jan 06 11:04:38 dittos kernel: rtw_8821ce 0000:01:00.0: firmware failed to leave lps state
lines 955-1000/1000 (END)
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: se>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed su>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x010>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_hel>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* K>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] >
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(10) fai>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
lines 955-976/1000 99%

Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap t>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: secu>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed succ>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x01010>
Jan 06 11:04:31 dittos kernel: [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helpe>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_gfx_enable_kcq [amdgpu]] *ERROR* KCQ>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm:amdgpu_device_ip_resume_phase2 [amdgpu]] *E>
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(10) failed
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
Jan 06 11:04:32 dittos kernel: [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
lines 955-977/1000 99%
```

Comment: ls -l /var/crash/